# Get the fan amount of a Facebook page for a given day in PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get the amount of fan of some facebook pages (that are not mine) in a 1 year period, i need to know what i have to do to get the fan counter of a page for a given day.
So it will be like

Current fan number: 18.000
Yesterday fan number: 17.800
[etc..]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not the administrator of the page you can not programaticaly access the insights.